# A backup mechanism to make docker volume persistent or available to localsystem or a mount point

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-volume

New to docker and don't fully understand the workaround. I am trying to create a docker container  to deploy a MongoDB instance. Since MongoDB requires a dbpath for setup, I am providing the dbpath as a volume. The problem I face is once the container is deleted I also lose the volume.
Now, how do I explicitly define the volume to localsystem or to a mount point.

```
docker run -d -p 2000:27017 -v /data/db --name mongoContainer mongo:4.2
```

If I am not wrong all the MongoDB collections created are being stored inside dbpath `/data/db` and once the container is deleted I lose the collections as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here you define your local volume only.

`docker run -d -p 2000:27017 -v /data/db --name mongoContainer mongo:4.2`

You **MUST** map your local directory to docker image folder

`docker run -d -p 2000:27017 -v /data/db:/inside/mongo_image/path --name mongoContainer mongo:4.2`

Always `-v /your/local/directory:/docker/directory`

`/inside/mongo_image/path` this should be the right path where mongodb will look for files.

Comment: I don't understand, isn't `/data/db' a fs of a specific container? And `/inside/mongo_image/path` is the local path where I want to store the files?

Comment: @nomadev95 No, you got it otherway.. Always `outside_world:docker_world`, here `-p 2000:27017`, you map your `localhost:2000` to `container:27017`

Comment: So it should be `-v local_directory_path:container_path`?

Comment: @nomadev95 YES.